# Exclude a number from java script random function

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to get a random number other than a given number and between the range in java script. for example the given number is 1 i need a random number between 0-4 other than the given number 1

used
`Math.floor(Math.random()*5)`

to get random number from 1 to 4

but if the given number is 1 it should not return that number from the range 0-4

i expect to get a number ranging from 2 to 4 if i give a number 1 as range is from 0-4

Comment: You question is not quite clear. Its confusing actually

Comment: maybe it would help if you add a call of a function with paramters and the wanted range/outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop and generate the random number until its not different than given.Below is the demo

```js
function getRandomNum(num){
  let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  while(x === num){
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
  }
  return x;
}
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = getRandomNum(1)
}
```

```html
<button>Get Random Number</button>
<div></div>
```